# Evaluate :$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1}\right)(x^2-x-1)}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

Evaluate :$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1}\right)(x^2-x-1) }\mathrm dx$$
How to evaluating this integral, I don't know how to do it, and any help  is welcome .

I tried using wolframalpha ,but the result is too complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: $y=1-x$ in the integral $I$, then show that $$2I=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2-x-1}$$

Comment: this is pretty nice :) $+1$

Comment: +1 Can you please add some detail?

Comment: By summing both expressions of the same integral: $I=\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-y}}{(\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{1-y})(y^2-y-1)}\,dy$ and $I=\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-x})(x^2-x-1)}\,dx$ one gets a simpler form: $I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2-x-1}$. Then, by changing $z=(2x-1)/\sqrt{5}$ reduces to $I=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\int_{-1/\sqrt{5}}^{1/\sqrt{5}}\frac{dz}{1-z^2}=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\tanh^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$, as given in Connor Evans' answer.

Comment: @Paul Enta Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the answer its

$$ -\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{5}\tanh^{-1}(\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{5}) $$

(by Maple)

Comment: it kinda reduces to $-2\tanh ^{-1}(\frac15)$

Comment: Not according to Maple buddy

Comment: Well, you did edit the post, buddy